# Can run Tomcat from within Eclipse, don't know how to run/debug my project

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

I have Java project that I formerly debugged using Sysdeo Launcher. Now I'd like to use the built-in support for Tomcat.

I am able to launch stand-alone Tomcat from within Eclipse that way (Server -> Runtime Environments, etc.), but when run it either loads only the web-apps installed in that Tomcat or does not load any web-app at all. I.e. I don't know how to tell Eclipse I want this project to be used as a web-app.

*Use Tomcat installation* results in Tomcat using web-apps defined in the stand-alone installation webapps dir
*Use workspace metadata* results in an empty Tomcat, i.e. no web-apps at all

*Add and Remove* on the server (in Servers view) yields 'There are no resources that can be added or removed from the server'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to convert this project to Dynamic Web Project. After that you should be able to deploy it on Tomcat within Eclipse.

This page has details : http://eclipse.dzone.com/tips/converting-java-project-dynami

Comment: thanks Shamit, i will try that and get back to give points then :)